# @StepScope Causing issue reader must be open before it can be read

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

This code work fine for me.

```
@Bean
    public ItemReader<ABC> itemReader1() {
        return new JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder<ABC>()
                .name("itemReader1")
                .dataSource(this.dataSource)
                .beanRowMapper(ABC.class)
                .sql("select * from abc")
                .build();
    }
```

But as soon as I started using @StepScope due to my some requirement I am getting following error

```
org.springframework.batch.item.ReaderNotOpenException: Reader must be open before it can be read.
```

The code is below with @StepScope

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public ItemReader<ABC> itemReader1() {
        return new JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder<ABC>()
                .name("itemReader1")
                .dataSource(this.dataSource)
                .beanRowMapper(ABC.class)
                .sql("select * from abc")
                .build();
    }
```

What is the fix for this so that I can use @StepScope?

Comment: The return type of your item reader bean definition method should be `JdbcCursorItemReader` or at least `ItemStreamReader` so that Spring Batch correctly creates the proxy and calls `open`/`update`/`close` methods when needed. See Michael's answer in the duplicate question for more details.

Comment: I have changed the return type to JdbcCursorItemReader but it is causing me new issue java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE' already exists. Even though I have singe data source and spring.batch.initialize-schema=ALWAYS
 added in properties file

Comment: That's another issue. Since you've set `spring.batch.initialize-schema=ALWAYS`, Spring Boot will try to create the tables on each application run, which you seem to have done more than once. Hence the script fails the second time. Make sure to delete the tables manually or update the script with something like `CREATE TABLE XXX IF NOT EXISTS`

Comment: This issue occur only in the case of @StepScope annotation. Reader working fine without StepScope.

Comment: Those are totally different and unrelated issues. Clean up your database, update your method to return `JdbcCursorItemReader` and it should work. Otherwise, please provide a minimal example that reproduces the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.